# Should I delay app.listen() in express.js app until assets are finished loading (express/heroku)?

Tags: node.js, heroku, express, assets

**Current setup**:
I have a current express app, with an asset-manager middleware that loads all the relevant assets. I deploy this app to heroku.

**Here's my problem:**
Occasionally I get a race condition where the app.listen() get's called BEFORE all the assets are done loading. This results in an error (500) on the first page load (unless I wait 5-10 secs). Subsequent page loads are fine. I am seeing this often on localhost, and occasionally in prod.

**Here's my question**:
What is considered the best practice for node apps? Should I wait to call app.listen() until the assets are finished loading? Is this considered a safe approach?

The same thing goes for loading i18n files and the such. Should I delay the app.listen() until all these files are loaded? Thoughts on best way to do this? Using Q or such?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only `.listen` when you're actually ready to *listen*, don't deceit your consumers!

```
assets.load(arg, arg, arg, function (err) {
     if (err) {
         throw new Error('uh-oh, no assets today!');
     }
     app.listen(port, then);
});
```

If you're having so much trouble dealing with static assets, you might want to consider building with [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com) or similar, and then [have Heroku use your Grunt workflow](https://github.com/buildfirst/heroku-grunt) before even executing your application.